# Cannot bind to the property or column... when add control

Tags: c#, forms, user-controls

when I try to add my own created control, to form, Visual Studio throws me error:
**Cannot bind to the property or column Item Name on the DataSource.
Parameter name: dataMember**
Can someone tell what, possibly I've done wrong, because placing whole class I think is unnecessary.

```
public partial class ctrlDetailGradation : BaseDetailsControl
{
    protected override DevExpress.XtraDataLayout.DataLayoutControl LayoutMain { get { return dataLayoutControl; } }

    public SALES_Gradation CurrentGradation
    {
        get { return GetXPOObject as SALES_Gradation; }
    }

    public bool bEditMode { get; set; }

    public ctrlDetailGradation():base(null)
    {
        OnConstructInit();
    }

    public ctrlDetailGradation(IMxPEditObjectHandlerInterface cEditObjInterface)
        : base(cEditObjInterface)
    {
        OnConstructInit();
    }

    private void OnConstructInit()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitLngStrings();
    }
...
```

there is part of code, it is simple class...
BaseDetailsControl is inherited from usercontrol

Comment: Please supply some code.

Comment: I have two user controls, on the first: spliter control(in panel1 grid, in panel 2 should be this control), tried just add it, another control can be added without any problems